# Retrieving Parent Hierarchy Entity

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "Material" (
    "MaterialId" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Material" PRIMARY KEY,
    "Content" TEXT NULL,
    "Title" TEXT NULL,
    "Paid" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Published" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "ParentMaterialId" TEXT NULL,
    "Dates" TEXT NULL,
    "Private" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_Material_Material_ParentMaterialId" FOREIGN KEY ("ParentMaterialId") REFERENCES "Material" ("MaterialId") ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

Each material can have an infinite sub materials inside them, and i would like:

1. Get the outer most ancestor material for a particular child.
2. Get the First ancestor that is `Paid` (**Paid** is a *boolean*)

I am not that good at complex database operations, so please be kind.

Comment: Am currently testing with **SQLite** but will latter switch to **sql-server**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both SQLite and SQL Server understand enough standard SQL to do a recursive tree walk like this:

```
WITH AllAncestors AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Material
  WHERE MaterialId = 12345

  UNION ALL

  SELECT parent.*
  FROM Material AS parent
  JOIN AllAncestors AS child ON child.ParentMaterialId = parent.MaterialId
)
SELECT *
FROM AllAncestors
WHERE ParentMaterialId IS NULL;
```

```
WITH AncestorsUntilPaid AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Material
  WHERE MaterialId = 12345

  UNION ALL

  SELECT parent.*
  FROM Material AS parent
  JOIN AncestorsUntilPaid AS child ON child.ParentMaterialId = parent.MaterialId
  WHERE child.Paid = 0   -- stops before the parent of a paid child
)
SELECT *
FROM AncestorsUntilPaid
WHERE Paid = 1;
```

Comment: would you help me convert this into MySql?
version: `'5.7.24'`

Comment: with MySql, adding the word `RECURSIVE` after `WITH` works on version 8.0 

http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/